# Should multi-language site using multi-site architecture have default language in base site?

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I am setting up a multi-language site using wordpress multi-site and wanted some feedback on the best approach/best practice.

I will have the following languages: en, sa, de, ru. 
en is default.

Should the domain.org by default be English, or should domain.org redirect to domain.org/en?

Comment: What is your goal? Why is this important?

Comment: @toscho My goal is to have a multi-language site setup, and I am using the multi-site architecture to achieve this. The default language of the site will be English. 

This is important because I haven't set up multi-language sites before and I wish to know the proper way (or best practice) of doing this, i.e., should the domain.org be English or should I have a distinct sub-site called domain.org/en and point domain.org to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subdomain for each language, set the main site to English. Then use the [plugin Multilingual Press](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press/) to chain these subdomains together. It has an option to redirect the visitor to the correct single page too if it is translated on another subdomain (not sure if that is part of the free version).

Subdomains are slightly better than sub directories for SEO because Google will detect the correct language with … a [higher probability](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192#1).