# Translate a site based on different themes

Tags: themes, multi-language, switch-theme

This is my first question on the site. First of all I want to apologize for my bad English.

I´m migrating a site to a WordPress theme, and I need a solution to translate the theme to *3 different languages*. I have the post translation on several custom post meta (title in Russian, title in Spanish, and so on). What i need is a simple solution to, based on a link, load a different theme so i can manage what to show on the site and URLs must to be viewed like `/en/` or `/es/`.

Answer (score 2):

Post meta is a bad place for translations, because you cannot search by default in these fields, and changing the search to do that results in rather slow and complex queries.

What you can do: set up WordPress as a [multi-site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), use the sub-sites option. Now create a new sub-site for each language, so you get sites with `en`, `es`, `ru` and so on.

To connect the translated posts, either

- create a separate table with relationships and a new metabox for the post editor to connect the posts from different languages, or
- install [Multilingual Press](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/) which does all this for you. Disclosure: I’m the lead developer for this plugin now.

Related: [Should multi-language site using multi-site architecture have default language in base site?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/64144/73)

Alternative for single-site: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85394/73

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. The Plugin seems to be a simple solution, but i´m exporting the database from another site build with ASP, and i have the database in XML. I export this XML to posts (custom taxonomies,categories,custom meta,etc)

Comment: Separate the export file by language and import each language in each sub-site. Test it on a test installation first. :)